# Polar decomposition of real matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Can we decompose real matrices in a way that is analogous to [polar decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) in the complex case?

What I mean is: given an invertible real matrix $M$, can we always write:
$$
M = OP,
$$

maybe uniquely, where $O$ is orthogonal, and $P$ is symmetric positive-definite?

Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition

Comment: @BillCook More or less... oh wait, I forgot symmetry!

Comment: The answer is yes.  This is a consequence of the spectral theorem, whereby $M^TM$ can be orthogonally diagonalized.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Wow. Can you explain more? (Or make it into an answer?)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer is yes. In fact, we don't need the spectral theorem to prove it.

Suppose that $M$ is a real invertible matrix.  Then $M^TM$ is positive definite and has the unique positive semidefinite square root $P = \sqrt{M^TM}$. Now, note that $P$ has the property $\|Px\| = \|Mx\|$ for all vectors $x$.

If $M$ is invertible, then $P$ is invertible as well, and we have $M = (MP^{-1})P$.  We note that $MP^{-1}$ is orthogonal since for all $y = Px$, we have
$$
\|MP^{-1}y\| = \|y\|
$$
Thus, we have a polar decomposition with $O =( MP^{-1})$ .

We note that this decomposition is unique. In particular, suppose $M = OP$ for orthogonal $O$ and positive $P$. then
$$
M^TM = PO^TOP = P^2
$$
And so, by the uniqueness of positive definite square roots, $P$ is uniquely determined.  Then we can rearrange $M = OP$ to find $O = MP^{-1}$ is also unique determined.

---

Things get a bit trickier when $M$ is not invertible, but we can still guarantee a (non-unique) polar decomposition.

Comment: This can also be derived easily from the singular value decomposition.

Comment: Wait...how do you prove that $PM^{-1}P=M$?

Comment: I think I meant to write $MP^{-1}$... the proof is pretty much the same, though.  The only other thing we need to show is that $M$ invertible $\iff$ $M^TM$ invertible $\iff$ $P$ invertible, which isn't too hard.

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: Oh yeah, like this it works! Thanks.

Comment: +1 Elegant proof!

Answer (score 0):

A derivation of the polar decomposition for a 2x2 matrix can be found on [Polar Decomposition](https://www.heavisidesdinner.com/LTFM/LTFM_book.html#polardecomposition)

I also elaborate the relation with SVD.
In short, shuffling around with the SVD decompostion:

$A= U \Sigma V^T$ = $(UV^T) (V \Sigma V^T) $= $R_{\theta} S_{AT}$

$S_{AT}$ scales along the principal axes of the ellipse defined by $A^T(unitcircle)$

$R_{\theta}$ rotates over the angle between the principal axes of $A$ and $A^T$

$A^{-1}=\left({\ \ U\ \mathrm{\Sigma}}^{-1}U^{-1}\right)^{-1}R_\theta$ = $S_A R_\theta$

$R_{\theta}$ rotates over the angle between the principal axes of $A$ and $A^T$

$S_{A}$ scales along the principal axes of the ellipse defined by $A(unitcircle)$

Comment: Is this voted down because it is wrong? not helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Theory of Polar Decomposition is described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition)
For the sake of simplicity we shall restrict our attention to real-valued non-singular square (invertible) matrices.
**Theorem.** Every such a matrix B can be decomposed as follows and the decomposition is unique:
$$
B = U Q
$$
Where $U =$ orthogonal matrix and $Q=$ symmetric positive definite matrix.
Instead of providing still another proof of the above theorem, I have decided to be practical and describe how to **numerically**
obtain the decomposition.
First define the transpose of the matrix multiplied with the original:
$$
P = B^T B = \left(B^TB\right)^T = P^T \quad \mbox{: symmetric}
$$
It follows that $P$ is symmetric and positive definite.
Then what we need is the square root of the matrix $P$. In order to understand how to obtain it, let's take a look at
[Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Square_root) for obtaining the square root
of a real positive number $p$:
$$
f(x) = x^2 - p\quad \Longrightarrow \\ x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{x_n^2-p}{2x_n} = \left(x_n + p\,x_n^{-1}\right)/2
$$
Let's do the same for our matrix $P$, iterations starting with the unit matrix:
$$
X_0 = I \quad ; \quad X_{n+1} = \left(X_n + P X_n^{-1}\right)/2 \quad ; \quad \sqrt{P} = \lim_{n\to\infty} X_n
$$
According to a
[MSE reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2288067/inverse-of-a-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix)
$X_n^{-1}$ is positive definite and symmetric, provided that $X_n$ is positive definite and symmetric. Products and sums
of positive definite and symmetric matrices are positive definite and symmetric too. Therefore,
by induction to $n$, it can be proved that $\sqrt{P}$ is positive definite and symmetric as well. Now define $Q=\sqrt{P}=Q^T$.
At last define $U = B Q^{-1}$ and prove that $U$ is orthogonal:
$$
U^{T}U = \left(B Q^{-1}\right)^T\left(B Q^{-1}\right) = \left(Q^{-1}\right)^T\left(B^TB\right)Q^{-1} = \\
\left(Q^T\right)^{-1} Q^2 Q^{-1} = \left(Q^{-1}Q\right)\left(QQ^{-1}\right) = II = I
$$
The conclusion looks like trivial:
$$
B = \left[B\left(B^TB\right)^{-1/2}\right]\left[\left(B^TB\right)^{1/2}\right]
$$
So far so good about theory. I want to talk about practice now, which in modern times is computer programming:

#### [Accompanying software](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/jaar2020/polair.htm)

My favorite programming language is [(Delphi) Pascal](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delphi_(software)).
First we need some standard matrix manipulation routines and a Newton-Raphson routine for calculating the matrix
square root. These are implemented in a Unit called 'Wiskunde'. The software is completed by testing if theory
works in practice as expected. The number of iterations in procedure 'Newton' has been determined as follows. A suitable stopping criterion is:
$$
\left|\left| X^2 - B^TB\,\right|\right| < \epsilon
$$
with $\epsilon = 10^{-10}$ and the norm of a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ defined as:
$$
\left|\left|A\right|\right| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}^2}
$$
Convergence is very fast. When cast in MathJax format the output looks like this:
$$ \small
\begin{bmatrix} 0.361048 & -0.297419 & -0.227079 \\ 0.171654 & -0.181309 & -0.338205 \\ -0.127762 & -0.074326 & -0.417988 \end{bmatrix} = \\ \small
\begin{bmatrix} 0.491571 & -0.868969 & -0.057015 \\ 0.599413 &  0.385125 & -0.701701 \\ -0.631714 & -0.310760 & -0.710187 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 0.361082 & -0.207928 & -0.050301 \\ -0.207928 & 0.211719 & 0.196967 \\ -0.050301 & 0.196967 & 0.547115 \end{bmatrix}
$$