# Showing each coset of a group can be associated to a unique symmetric matrix

Tags: group-theory

$f$ is an automorphism where $f: GL(3,ℝ)\rightarrow GL(3,ℝ)$ and $f(A)=(A^{-1})^T$

Let $T(3)$ be the group of fixed points of f. How do we show that for each coset (both left and right) of $T(3)$ there can be associated a unique symmetric matrix?

I see that $T(3)$ basically represents the set of orthogonal matrices $(A^{-1}=A^T)$, but i'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

This follows directly from the [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) as explained in [Polar decomposition of real matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456320/polar-decomposition-of-real-matrices).

Comment: I've never heard of this before but will check it out, thank you.