# Positive definite operator on vector space of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, positive-definite

I'm reading a paper now that works with operators on the vector space of real $d\times d$ matrices (such an operator can be thought of as a 4-dimensional tensor). The definition of positive-definiteness in this setting would seem to be the analogue of the usual one: we have the standard inner product $\langle A,B\rangle = \text{tr}(A^TB)$ and we say the operator $\mathcal{M}$ is positive-definite if for all matrices $A$ we have $\text{tr}(A^T\mathcal{M}A)>0$.

However, the definition this paper uses is that the above holds for all *symmetric* matrices $A$. What's the difference (if any?)? Why should this be the right definition (and is it?)?

More generally, is there a good reference on linear algebra over such spaces with special structure as the space of matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between your definition and the definition given in the paper. The reason is the following.

Given any matrix $T$ you can write it as $T=PO$ where $P$ is a positive matrix and $O$ is an orthogonal matrix. This is known as *polar decomposition*. Usually the proof is given for complex matrices but the same proof works for real  matrices as well. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456320/polar-decomposition-of-real-matrices) for details.

Now in your situation if you start with any matrix $T$, you have $$tr(T^TMT)=tr([PO]^TM[PO])=tr\big(O^T\bigg(P^TMP\bigg)O\big)=tr(P^TMP).$$

The last equality  is due to the fact that $tr(AB)=tr(BA)$ and $O^TO=OO^T=Id$ . Therefore it is enough to check the inequality for positive matrices.