# Linear transformation as product of isometry and unique positive linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, isometry

I've read that any linear transformation on a finite dimensional inner-product space can be written as the product of an isometry and a unique positive linear transformation.

I've proven this if the transformation is non-singular. How can it be shown in the general case?

Comment: Are you thinking to the "polar decomposition" (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1456320) ?

Comment: Yes, that looks to be exactly what I'm looking for, thanks.