# Product of hermitian and unitary matrix is a square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am unable to think of a way to prove this result:
Show that every square matrix is a product of a hermitian matrix and an unitary matrix.

I want to prove it using the spectral theorem.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually done via the "polar decomposition" of a matrix; more information on that is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition).  [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1456535/81360) details what that looks like for real matrices; a similar proof applies in the complex case, where the $T$'s are replaced by $*$'s.

Comment: How can the spectral theorem be used to prove it?

Comment: The spectral theorem provides a convenient way to show that $A^*A$ has a unique positive definite square root.

Comment: Could you please sketch the entire proof?

Comment: @TejasP I have no intention of doing so.  This is a standard result which you can find in most linear algebra textbooks.