# Uniqueness of $UV^T$ of non-singular matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ non-singular matrix. Then we can take many alternative SVD from from $A$. Like $A = U_1 \Sigma V_1^\top = U_2 \Sigma V_2^\top = \cdots$ where $\Sigma$ is an ordered diagonal (invertible) matrix of singular values. Can we say that $U_1V_1^\top = U_2V_2^\top = \cdots$ ? I.e., I am curious about the uniqueness of $UV^T$.

Comment: $UV^T$ is the unitary factor in the polar decomposition of $A$. It is uniquely determined by $A(A^TA)^{-1/2}$ when $A$ is non-singular.

Comment: @user1551
Thank you for your perfect reply!

Comment: [Possibly related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1805191/339790)

Comment: [See also this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1456535/81360)

Comment: Thanks to everyone who commented!