# Calculating polar decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I compute the left and right polar decompositions of a matrix by hand? I understand the definition of the decomposition but not how it is calculated.

For instance are the left and right polar decompositions of this matrix different, and how do I compute them?

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -3\\
1 & 6\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 2):

The polar decomposition is strongly related with the Singular Value Decomposition.
**The SVD looks as follows:**
$$A=U\mathrm{\Sigma}V^T$$
$$V\ contains\ the\ eigenvectors\ of\   A^TA\ as\ columns$$
$$U\ contains\ the\ eigenvectors\ of\   AA^T\ as\ columns$$
You do not need to calculate both $U$ and $V$, since they can be derived from the other:
$$(1)\  U=\left[\begin{matrix}|&|\\u_1&u_2\\|&|\\\end{matrix}\right]\   with\ u_i=\frac{Av_i}{\sigma_i}$$

$$(2)\  V=\left[\begin{matrix}|&|\\v_1&v_2\\|&|\\\end{matrix}\right]\   with\ v_i=\frac{A^Tu_i}{\sigma_i}$$

**The polar decomposition looks as follows:**

$$(3)\ A=\ \left(U\mathrm{\Sigma}U^{T}\right)\   \left(UV^T\right)=S_A\ R_\theta$$
$$(4)\ A=U\mathrm{\Sigma}V^T=\left(UV^T\right)\left(V\mathrm{\Sigma}V^T\right)={R_\theta} S_{AT}$$

So to calculate the polar decomposition you

1. Calculate the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and eigenvectors $v_i$ of $A^TA$
2. The matrix $\Sigma$ contains $\sigma_i=\sqrt{\lambda_i}$ on its diagonal
3. Derive eigenvectors $u_i$ of $AA^T$ using (1)
4. Now calculate $UV^T$
5. if I am not mistaken $\left(V\mathrm{\Sigma}V^{T}\right)=A^TA$, so (3) can be completed
6. Now you need to calculate  $AA^T$ or $\left(U\mathrm{\Sigma}U^{T}\right)$, to complete  (4)

   A geometric analysis of polar decomposition can be found on [Heaviside's Dinner](https://www.heavisidesdinner.com/LTFM/LTFM_book.html).
   An interactive geogebra plot can be found on the geogebra website: [polar decomposition](https://www.geogebra.org/m/aavwd628).

Answer (score 0):

A brute force (numerical) method for obtaining the right polar decomposition has been presented in
[this answer at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456320/polar-decomposition-of-real-matrices/3903199#3903199).
When applied to the OP's problem (`Test4`) we get an outcome like:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    2.000000 &  -3.000000 \\
    1.000000 &  6.000000
\end{bmatrix} = \\
\begin{bmatrix}
    0.894427 & -0.447214 \\
    0.447214 &  0.894427
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    2.236068 &  0.000000 \\
    0.000000 &  6.708204
\end{bmatrix}
$$
However, when searching for the number $0.447214$ on the internet, we find that it's approximately equal to
[What is 1 over square root of 5?](https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-1-over-square-root-of-5).
So let's do an educated guess:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 2 & -3 \\
 1 & 6
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
 2/\sqrt{5} & -1/\sqrt{5} \\
 1/\sqrt{5} & 2/\sqrt{5}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \sqrt{5} & 0 \\
 0 & 3\sqrt{5}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
It is noticed that the above question is similar to [another one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706262/find-the-polar-decomposition/).

EDIT. But the above is, of course, overkill.
Here comes a much simpler solution. First form the transpose times the original matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -3 \\ 1 & 6 \end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -3 \\ 1 & 6 \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ -3 & 6 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -3 \\ 1 & 6 \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 5 & 0 \\ 0 & 45 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Then make the following Ansatz:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & c \end{bmatrix}^2 =
\begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & c \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & c \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} a^2 & 0 \\ 0 & c^2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 0 \\ 0 & 45 \end{bmatrix}
$$
So the square root of a diagonal matrix is extremely simple; just take the square roots of the diagonal elements:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & c \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{5} & 0 \\ 0 & 3\sqrt{5} \end{bmatrix}
$$
At last, the orthogonal matrix is found with:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -3 \\ 1 & 6 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{5} & 0 \\ 0 & 3\sqrt{5} \end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \\
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -3 \\ 1 & 6 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1/\sqrt{5} & 0 \\ 0 & 1/(3\sqrt{5}) \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} 2/\sqrt{5} & -1/\sqrt{5} \\ 1/\sqrt{5} & 2/\sqrt{5} \end{bmatrix}
$$
Same conclusion:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 2 & -3 \\
 1 & 6
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
 2/\sqrt{5} & -1/\sqrt{5} \\
 1/\sqrt{5} & 2/\sqrt{5}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \sqrt{5} & 0 \\
 0 & 3\sqrt{5}
\end{bmatrix}
$$